# nginx: http to https not working on chrome

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I've got this nginx configuration to redirect http to https:

```
# http redirects to https
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ...
}
```

It works properly on firefox. If I add in `/etc/hosts` entry like:

`127.0.0.1       my-custom-domain.com` to make sure I have domain that was never used, in firefox if I enter `my-custom-domain.com`, I get this:

[image]

Works as expected, it redirects to https.

But if I do the same on chrome, I get this:

[image]

Chrome only opens `https` one if I explicitly enter `https://my-custom-domain.com`.. Not sure why it behaves differently on chrome.

P.S. I read some people say that `server_name` must not be `_` and have specific name, but it works the same even if I enter `sever_name my-custom-domain.com;`

P.S.S I'm using `1.23.0-alpine` nginx docker image.

**Update**

It looks like this issue is related with nginx docker image. I was not able to reproduce this with nginx installed locally. Though nginx images with tags `nginx:1.18.0`, `nginx:1.23.0`, `nginx:1.23.0-alpine` all had same issue.

Comment: Can't replicate with nginx 1.18.0 from with Ubuntu 22.04, Chrome 103 & FF 102. Chrome behave just like FF, correctly redirecting. Could be an extension or leftover rule on Chrome?

Comment: Mine is 1.23.0 nginx version. Chrome is 103. But I got this issue reported from some of the customers, and was able to reproduce myself. So I would not really be able to force anyone to configure chrome to work as intended (if its chrome configuration issue)..

Comment: If you point a throwaway subdomain (perhaps from a DDNS) to the server IP and test it with GTMetrix, do you get "An error occurred fetching the page: Server closed connection without sending any data back", or do you get the page loaded? Also since the problem happen only on HTTP, are you and your customer using similar software like corp VPN, anti-malware protection etc?

Comment: @Martheen no. No vpn, no special malware protection. We even have different OS, I use Ubuntu, he uses MacOs. Also I could reproduce this locally.

Comment: Ah, could be some bug in non-Windows Chrome

Comment: @Martheen it looks like its related with nginx docker image. I tried to reproduce it with nginx installed on my local ubuntu (1.18.0 version) and it was working correctly. Same as you reported. I tried same configuration as I have with my nginx docker image.. Not sure why docker image behaves differently.

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: @accdias ok will try. Though not sure if its off topic. I see plenty of questions with same topic here.

Comment: SO is for coding questions and yours is about infrastructure management. SuperUser is better suited, IMHO. You can check SO directives to be sure. I'm not enforcing anything, BTW. I'm just trying to make SO a better place :-D. Check the box "Ask About" in (https://stackoverflow.com/tour).